# IIS 8 - How to view a history of requests made to the web server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a web server that is currently running my asp.net mvc website. I am making a connection to an external website that sends a request back to the server via a specific URL and attaches the information sent as a query string.

I have no idea if this query string being sent is in the correct format but I do know that the action result function is being called. I need to see what requests are being sent to the server so that I can see the format in which the request was sent.

I know how to view the currently executing requests using the request monitor, but this is not enough since you can miss the request if it happens to fast.

Is it possible to view a history of requests that have occurred on the server? So that I may find the one that I need after the request has occurred.

Comment: You could see what is in the inetpub/logs folder on the web server and have a look at the files (providing logging is turned on). There are also programs what open these files to make them easier to read..Also download Fiddler in the browser and look at this when accessing the website.

Comment: Thanks this helped :). I managed to find a some information on it here: [HTTP Logging](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httplogging).

Comment: glad it was helpful